# How to get selected checkboxes from table in multiple rows & columns and send as post response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I've an account statement table (mapped from response) with date and two other columns which has checkboxes.

**View (HTML)**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Statement Period</th>
    <th>Mail Address</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oct 2018</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nov 2018</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dec 2018</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button ng-click="getSelectedData">Proceed</button<
```

Based on $index (array id), I want get selected checkbox(s) from each row and send as array like below JSON format;

*Note: selected checkbox represents "Y" and other one represents "N"*

**JSON Array (Expected Response)**

```
[
  {
    "isEmail": "Y",
    "isMail": "N",
    "month": "12",
    "year": "2018"
  },
  {
    "isEmail": "Y",
    "isMail": "N",
    "month": "10",
    "year": "2018"
  }
]
```

I want to send POST response like above format with couple of params (email address & physical address). I've tried a for loop, but seems luck runs out from this one.

**Controller JS**

```
$scope.sendStatementList = function(i) {
  var listLenght = $scope.accountStatementList.lenght;

  for (var i = 0; i < listLenght; i++) {
    var selectItem = $scope.accountStatementList[i];

    return selectItem;
  }

  console.log(selectItem);
};
```

I've tried multiple approaches, but still loss and no idea about right approach. Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S. Here is plunker ([demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KuPZbqL885iOakNlYwJ)) for my query.

Comment: A good practice is to provide `name` to form input elements.

Comment: sorry about that, just added plunker demo as P.S. Thanks for notifying @Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 https://next.plnkr.co/edit/6GLQtI85vPE0V98x
```

Just create another array mapped with your existing one:

```
 $scope.finalResponse = $scope.statementListRespone.map(function(st){
    return { 
      "month" : $filter('date')(st, "MM") , 
      "year" : $filter('date')(st, "yyyy"), 
      "isMail": "N", 
      "isEmail": "N"};
  });
```

And update your markup with binding to the other array, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="email-{{$index}}" name="email" ng-modal="email" 
    ng-model="finalResponse[$index]['isEmail']" 
    ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'">
```

So, on button click: you can simply send your *finalResponse* array.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this. I'll try it shortly and update here.